# What is the difference between keywords and reserved words in Java?

Tags: java, syntax, keyword, reserved-words

I have seen this popular [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078908/what-is-the-difference-between-keyword-and-reserved-word) but the Java docs tends to say a different answer in this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) The stackoverflow link answer that is accepted says a reserved word will be reserved for future use and keywords are special words part of language. It then says goto in Java is not a keyword but is a reserved word. However the Java docs. link that I posted literally calls goto a reserved word and a keyword. In that case what is truly the difference between these terms? Do they have special meaning in consideration to Java. I do not think my question is a duplicate because the Java docs. says the opposite from the accepted answer.

Comment: The docs clearly says: *Here is a list of keywords in the Java [...]. You cannot use any [...]. The keywords const and goto are reserved, even though they are not currently used.*. Then `goto` is a **reserved keyword**.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Is there a difference between a reserved word and a reserved keyword? The StackOverflow link talks about reserved words not reserved keywords.

Comment: Hey @Gushdbau could you provide some insight as to what challenge you are trying to solve by obtaining this information? This could potentially help us understand what you are trying to solve and we can reach the solution by working backwards.

Comment: I am just trying to understand the meaning between reserved words and keywords and then was thinking to apply or refer it to Java because I am most familiar with Java. However, even though reserved words and keywords seem to be language agnostic terms, it is not seeming to be the case and causing more confusion when relating to Java.

Answer (score 0):

**key words** - words in Java that have a pre-defined meaning
**reserved key words** - words in Java that are keywords but they are not currently in use and don't have a function in code.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Comment: Is there a difference between reserved keywords and reserved words then? Because the original StackOverflow link talks about reserved words not reserved keywords. @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere

Comment: Hey @Gushdbau, that Stackoverflow link is targeting general programming, where as your question is specifically focused towards Java. It's up to the Java team to decide how they wish to specifically define the meaning in their use case. Can you find any Java documentation where they use the term "reserved words"? I couldn't find any. I know you already saw the java documentation, but it might be difficult to extract the meaning since they don't directly define the words.

Comment: Hey @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere, I do could not find any Java documentation for reserved words. I thought there would be because that StackOverflow link was tagged as a language agnostic and the accepted answer says goto in Java is a reserved word but not a keyword but Java doc. does not mention the reserved word term, which conflicts with that link.

Comment: Well if they say that about Java and you think it is a significant mistake you can edit that answer and make it say reserved key word instead.

Comment: I will need to be on this page for some time and contribute to make the comment there, which I am fine with. Unless you want to, but it is fine otherwise. Thanks.